# Qt - Crash when I use a tcp socket to write data if tcp server first closed and then reopened connection

Tags: qt, sockets, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I'm moving my application from Qt 4.7 to Qt 6.3. In Qt 4.7 all works fine. In Qt 6.3 I have some issues when tcp server closes connection, I establish again connection, and I try to write data.

This is the function I use to write to socket:

```
void NetworkFacility::Write(QTcpSocket& oTCPSocket, const QVariant& oV)
{
    //Controls Socket is valid
    if (oTCPSocket.state() == QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState)
    {
        QByteArray block;                           //ByteArray to serialiaze object
        MyPacket oPacket;                           //Packet to send

        //Set Size of QVariant object
        oPacket.setPacketSize(getQVariantSize(oV));
        //Set QVariant
        oPacket.setTransport(oV);

        //Create stream to write on ByteArray
        QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        //Sets version
        out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_7);

        //Serializes
        out << oPacket;
        //TX to socket
        oTCPSocket.write(block);
    }
}
```

I manage disconnection this way:

```
void MyClient::remoteNodeDisconnected()
{
  m_pTCPSocket->flush();
  m_pTCPSocket->close();

}
```

```
void MyClient::ManagesTCPError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError socketError)
{
    //Clears last packets
    m_pTCPSocket->flush();
}
```

This is connection portion of code after disconnection:

```
m_pTCPSocket->connectToHost(m_sIpAddress, m_iIpPort);
//Waits connection
if (m_pTCPSocket->waitForConnected(MSEC_WAIT_FOR_CONNECTION))
{
  //Print connected and exit from while loop
  break;
}
```

Finally this is the way in which I manage the remote server connecte:

```
void MyClient::remoteNodeConnected()
{
    //Improve Network latency on this connection
    m_pTCPSocket->setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::LowDelayOption, 1);
}
```

The issue is that on the first connection all works fine. If the server disconnects (i.e. I umplugg the server cable in my LAN or I shutdown and restarts the server application) and then connects again the call to:

```
oTCPSocket.write(block);
```

in Networkfacility::Write method generates a crash.

Why the write method generates a crash after reconnection?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by removing completely th oTCPSocket instance.

```
void MyClient::remoteNodeDisconnected()
{
  m_pTCPSocket->flush();
  m_pTCPSocket->close();
  m_pTCPSocket.deleteLater();
  m_pTCPSocket = 0;
}
```